# Adding a .xcassets file to an Xcode framework project

Tags: xcode, cocoa

I've got a *framework* project that uses a number of images. As it stands I just drag these images into the project so that they sit alongside my source files:

[image]

When I embed this project into a separate *app* project, I can access these resources as expected.

Ideally, I'd now like to organize my framework images with a *.xcassets* file. Unlike *app* projects, the *framework* project template doesn't provide one of these by default, so I've added one manually using the *File > New* menu. Unfortunately when I rebuild the framework and re-embed it, I can no longer access the images. Is what I'm trying to do possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I can make out, the answer to my question is *yes, sort of...*

To make use of the `NSImage(named: ...)` API one of two things needs to be true: either the image should exist within the app's main bundle, or (to paraphrase the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSImage_Class/)):

> *[there should be]* an *[NSImage]* object whose name was set explicitly using the setName: method and currently resides in the image cache.

In the case where the image resides in an embedded framework, the first isn't true since the framework is a separate bundle, and there's no way of adding to the main bundle at runtime. This leaves the second approach.

Whenever your code is going to use `NSImage(named: ...)` make sure you've already loaded the image using some other way, then set its name:

```
let bundle = NSBundle(forClass: MyFrameworkClass.self)
let image = bundle.imageForResource(name) // image in the framework .xcassets
image.setName(name)
```

I don't know how much use this is, and you should definitely be aware of the notes in the docs about how the image cache operates, but it is at least one way of storing images in a .xcassets folder in one bundle, then accessing them from another.

Comment: Hi Paul. Any suggestions how to use the image within a storyboard or xib? When I try, I get an error: **Could not load the "<ImageName>" image referenced from a nib in the bundle with identifier "<BundleName>"**

Comment: Thanks for the info. Shame that Apple require such workarounds when reuse of resources should really be encouraged where possible, but at least it's achievable.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to access assets in a subproject (framework etc.) you need to make sure that you are collecting them from their own bundle since they are not part of the `Main Bundle`.

You can do that simply with this **Swift 4** code:

```
let bundle = Bundle(for: type(of: self))
let image = UIImage(named: "imageName", in: bundle, compatibleWith: nil)
```

Comment: Hi Foti. Any suggestions how to use the image within a storyboard or xib? When I try, I get an error: **Could not load the "<ImageName>" image referenced from a nib in the bundle with identifier "<BundleName>"**

Comment: @TheNeil Storyboards will only see images in the main bundle. If you use CocoaPods you can use `resources` in your podspec and all your framework assets will eventually be included in the main bundle: https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html#tab_resources.

Another way would be to create a `.bundle` file along with your framework but the consumer of your framework needs to *manually* drag the `.bundle` file in his project.